# Rails MiniTest after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm experimenting with TDD and MiniTest. Now I want to test simple `after_create` callback which will be pretty easy in RSpec but not so simple I guess with MiniTest. I've got below `User` and `Wallet` model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_wallet

  has_one :wallet, dependent: :destroy
end


class Wallet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How to test `after_create` with MiniTest? I have my doubts whether I should be doing this at all but well... I think this is a part of TDD.

Comment: you mean you want to test that `:create_wallet` will be called after user created ?

Comment: @LamPhan exactly!

Comment: What do you mean by "it will be easy in rspec"? Unless you're "cheating" and using some sort of `expect(...)to have_after_create` helper, implementing a test in either framework would look almost identical.

Comment: @TomLord In RSpec I would simply check if the number of Wallet models has changed. I read somewhere that I need to mock something in MiniTest.

Comment: `check if the number of Wallet models has changed` is not sure that `:create_wallet` will be called, for example, other could add another callback that create wallet then halt the callback chain -> your test case pass although `:create_wallet`  not be called.

Comment: So what will be the best solution if no such?

Comment: @mr_muscle No, I don't see why you would need to mock anything. You can check that the number of wallets has changed in a virtually-identical way to rspec. I'd suggest having a go, and asking for assistance with your attempted implementation if it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean, you **could** utilise some sort of mock by explicitly checking that the `create_wallet` has been called, but personally I'm rarely a fan of such tests, as they're only testing *implementation* rather than *behaviour*.

Comment: Minitest has the `assert_difference` and `assert_no_difference` methods, which seem to do what you want, in terms of matching the behaviour "In RSpec I would simply check if the number of Wallet models has changed." Although the `assert_called` suggested in the answer below certainly looks to do the job, too!

Comment: @TomLord i have thought about `implementation` vs. `behaviour` test cases before, there're trade-off, with `behaviour` we avoid write test cases so detail, for example with this question, in future customer change the way to create `wallet` through another process, then we must get rid of whole this test cases, meanwhile with behavior test case, we don't care how implement, just verify input/output. On the other hand, `behaviour` also so general that make it's hardly to cover all error-prone behind the code that haven't revealed yet until user experience them on Production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you should test that the method `:create_wallet` will be called `only one time` after a user created. Then for sure you could create another test case for the method `:create_wallet` itself.

```rb
require "test_helper"
require "active_support/testing/method_call_assertions"

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::MethodCallAssertions

  test "after create callback" do
    user = User.new(...)
    assert_called(user, :create_wallet, times: 1) do
      user.save
    end
  end

  test "create wallet" do
    user = User.new(...)
    assert_changes -> {user.wallet.blank?}, from: true, to: false do
      user.save
    end

    # or assert_equal
    user = User.create(...) 
    assert_equal Wallet.last.user_id, user.id
    assert_equal 1, Wallet.where(user_id: user.id).count
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it should be `from: true, to: false` inside `assert_change` block.

Comment: @mr_muscle i fixed, you also could `assert_equal`

Comment: You might want to use `assert_difference 'Wallet.count', 1 do ... end`, rather than using `assert_changes` like this, because it's more directly measuring the end result. But both ultimately do the same thing!